# Trying to attach a GCS bucket to Datalore

Tags: google-cloud-storage, datalore

(I asked this also on Datalore's forum. There doesn't seem to be much going on there -- so I'm asking here in the hope of a better/quicker response.)

I'm having trouble attaching GCS buckets. The documentation is sparse. All that I could find  is [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datalore/use-s3-buckets.html), which simply says:

> In the New datasource dialog, fill in the fields and click Save and close.

Here's that dialog and I'm not sure what information to put here.

[image]

### What I tried

**GCS datasource name**

I believe it's for reference within Datalore, correct? So can I just put anything here? I wrote "patant-data-ors".

**bucket**

Options I tried:

1. patent-data-ors (this is the name of the bucket)
2. storage.googleapis.com/patent-data-ors
3. patent-data-ors.storage.googleapis.com

Also tried 2 and 3 with `https://`.

**key_file_content**

I left it blank. I'm guessing it's for private buckets? Mine is publicly accessible.

---

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I do not know the Datalore interface. General tips: 1) To use the storage APIs, authorization is required. 2) Most likely bucket name is `patent-data-ors` or `gs://patent-data-ors`. 3) `key_file_content` is probably the `private_key` from the service account JSON file. Sometimes it is the entire file (sometimes stripped of newlines). 4) Please post an answer once you figure this out.

Comment: I found this link on [GCS bucket mounting](https://blog.jetbrains.com/datalore/2021/11/25/new-in-datalore-r-and-scala-notebooks-google-cloud-bucket-mounting-and-more/#gcs-bucket-mounting). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should paste the whole text from .JSON file.
To get this file, follow these steps after you created a bucket in the project:

1. In the Google Cloud menu, select `IAM & Admin`.
2. Go to `Service accounts` and create a new account.
3. In the section `Grant this service account access to project` select the role `Storage admin`. You can find it by typing in filters.
4. Open the created account and go to `Keys` tab. Add a new key as a JSON file. Then open it, copy the text and paste it to `GCS key file content` field in Datalore.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I believe I was able to sort this out doing what you suggested here. I moved away from Datalore, though. Might revisit again.